# Undefined method accept_modal for Capybara::Webkit::Driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, capybara-webkit

In a Rails app, I'm using RSpec (with Capybara Webkit) to test that a Delete link is working.

In my Rails template I have:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', movie_path(@movie), 
                      method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And this is my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Deleting a movie", js: true do
  it "destroys the movie and shows the movie listing without the deleted movie" do
    movie = Movie.create(movie_attributes)

    visit movie_path(movie)

    page.accept_confirm do
     click_link 'Delete'
    end

    expect(current_path).to eq(movies_path)
    expect(page).not_to have_text(movie.title)
  end
end
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `accept_modal' for #<Capybara::Webkit::Driver:0x007febc2214908>
```

It's using the right driver (Webkit) but it doesn't seem to find `accept_modal` (which must be called by `page.accept_confirm`).

I'm using:

```
capybara (2.14.0)
capybara-webkit (1.1.0)
rails (5.1.1)
rspec (3.6.0)
rspec-rails (3.6.0)
```

Note that using **the following will work**:

```
click_link 'Delete'
page.driver.browser.accept_js_confirms
```

But I'd like to understand why `accept_confirm` does not.

Answer (score 0):

The capybara-webkit you are using is massively out of date (1.1.0 was realeased in December of 2013), didn't support the unified Capybara modal API (it didn't exist when capybara-webkit 1.1.0 was released), and didn't derive it's driver class from Capybara::Driver::Base, so you don't get the "NotSupportedByDriverError" you would get nowadays if a feature was not yet implemented/supported by a driver - update to the latest capybara-webkit (you may need to use the master branch if you want to use capybara 2.14.0+, otherwise you'll be stuck at capybara 2.13.x)