# testing js confirmation dialogs using Capybara Webkit Rspec

Tags: rspec, webkit, capybara

I'm having nightmares trying to test a simple JS pop-up delete confirmation.
"modal" here is another word for "JS confirmation pop-up"

My question seems identical to this one
[Undefined method accept_modal for Capybara::Webkit::Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401643/undefined-method-accept-modal-for-capybarawebkitdriver)

But the answer suggested an out-of-date webkit gem 1.1.0. But that is the latest gem?

```
subject { page }

it "should.....",
 :type => :feature,
 :driver => :webkit,
 :js => true do

.....

page.accept_confirm do
click_button("Delete")
end

.....
```

but the test crashes with the error message

```
 Failure/Error: page.accept_confirm {}

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `accept_modal' for #<Capybara::Webkit::Driver:0x000000078cc010>
```

"Undefined method accept modal" !?!?!  This is a basic reason someone would want to use Webkit, so there has to be a solution. Any suggestions? Is this a common problem. Do many people use Webkit?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help rescue this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer to the linked question - you're using an out of date version of `capybara-webkit`, probably because you've locked the version of `capybara` to the latest version which the latest released version of `capybara-webkit` doesn't support.  `accept_modal` was added to `Capybara::Webkit::Driver` around version 1.3.0 -  If you're getting that error you're using a version before that.  Update to the latest release of `capybara-webkit` (1.14.0 - which may require you to move back a version or two of `capybara`), or use the master branch of `capybara-webkit` if you need to use the latest Capybara release.

Comment: BOOHYAH!! Updated the Gemfile to set gem "capybara", "2.13.0" and gem "capybara-webkit", "1.14.0" and we're testing JS confirmations!!!

Comment: @JustMattfornow Yes - but you weren't using the latest versions.  You were running the latest version of `capybara` but since there is no released version of `capybara-webkit` that supports that version of `capybara` bundler went back and found an ancient version of `capybara-webkit` which doesn't specify limits on versions it's compatible with.  Running `bundle outdated` would have shown you how out of date the versions were.

Comment: @JustMattfornow Also, since you're specifying the `capybara-webkit` version you don't really need to specify the capybara version since `capybara-webkit` already specifies the versions it supports (in fact you don't even need to specify `capybara` at all since it's a dependency of `capybara-webkit`).  Additionally if you find you need the latest capybara version you can specify `gem "capybara-webkit", github: 'thoughbot/capybara-webkit'` since the master branch supports the newest releases of Capybara

Comment: @JustMattfornow it’s standard gem/bundler behavior

Comment: Wow. Okay... So I don't need to specify Capybara at all? That would have then not raised the issue. D'oh, I did wonder about that but confidence erred on adding "because it can't do any harm"

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be useful for you:

```
When(/^I confirm popup$/) do
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
end
```

I am using this step for pressing OK button on pop-up.

Comment: Hello @Siarhei Manko. The problem was that I was including "gem 'capybara' in my Gemfile. My Gemfile included "gem capybara-webkit'" and therefore capybara would have been pulled in to the gem list as a dependency. But because I was specifying gem 'capybara' bundler had to find a version of webkit that was compatible. This caused a mess and so I just deleted the capybara gem from the gemfile and let bundler manage the dependencies.